# Current State Query / Architecture

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I expect this is a common enough use-case, but I'm unsure the best way to leverage database features to do it. Hopefully the community can help.

Given a business domain where there are a number of attributes to make up a record. We can just call these a,b,c

Each of these belong to a parent record, of which there can be many,

Given an external datasource that will post updates to those attributes, at arbitrary times, and typically only a subset, so you get instructions like

```
z:{a:3}
```

or

```
y:{b:2,c:100}
```

What are good ways to be able to query postgres for the 'current state', ie. wanting a single row result that represents the most recent value for all of a,b,c, for each of the parent records.

current state looks overall like

```
x:{a:0, b:0, c:1}
y:{a:1, b:2, c:3}
z:{a:2, b:65, c:6}
```

If it matters, The difference in time between updates on a single value could be arbitrarily long

I am deliberately avoiding having a table that keeps updating and writing an individual row for the state because the write-contention could be a problem, and I think there must be a better overall pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a bit theorical - but in essence you are describing a top-1-per-group problem. In Postgres, you can use `distinct on` for this.

Assuming that your table is called `mytable`, where attributes are stored in column `attribute`, and that column `ordering_id` defines the ordering of the rows (that could be a timestamp or an serial for example), you would phrase the query as:

```
select distinct on (attribute) t.*
from mytable t
order by attribute, ordering_id desc
```